# Disabling non-available options in RSpec 2.6

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

In my primary ~/.rspec file, I have the option `--order default` set up.

I've just started work on a Rails project that uses an older version of RSpec (I'm not sure exactly which of the RSpec gems in the gemfile is the key one, but all are 2.6.something)

When I run bundle exec rspec with the new project, it throws the exception `invalid option: --order (OptionParser::InvalidOption)`.

I've been able to fix this by deleting the option from the main RSpec file, but obviously that's not really what I want to do. But what I've been able to find in RSpec's documentation about overriding locally all refers to either changing options or introducing new ones - not to ignoring them altogether.

The ./.rspec file in my project root has nothing but the option `--color`, but evidently that's not a command to use only that option.

Is there a way to tell it locally to ignore the line whose syntax it doesn't understand?

Thanks all.

Comment: what does this option suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom config file or set project's one explicitly

```
rspec spec/ --options .rspec
```

http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files#rspec-ignores-./.rspec-when-custom-options-file-is-used

It also ignores `~/.rspec` not only `./.rspec` as it specified in documentation